# How to reduce number of rows being scanned?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

- `match_overall_test` - contains details of 1.4m tennis matches played - one match per row
- `match_stat_test` - contains stats for 400k of the matches in `match_overall_test` - one match per row

I'm trying to optimise a number of queries that access these two tables. As an MRE I've reduced one down to:

```
SELECT mot.id_, mst.p1_serve_1
FROM belgarath.match_overall_test AS mot
LEFT OUTER JOIN belgarath.match_stat_test AS mst ON mot.id_ = mst.match_overall_test_id
WHERE mot.p1_id = 19
```

Using `EXPLAIN` I got the following result:

[image]

From this I can see that the index on `p1_id` in `belgarath.match_overall_test` is doing its job and the query only scans a fraction of the records in that table.

As there is a one to one relationship between the two tables I have an FK on the `match_stat_test.match_overall_test_id` column going to the PK in `belgarath.match_overall_test`. I was hoping this would mean the query would only scan the records in `match_stat_test` that were scanned by `match_overall_test` however it is scanning all 400k of them.

Is there a way for me to amend the fields/indexing/FKs to speed things up by reducing the number of records scanned in `match_stat_test`?

Here are the `CREATE TABLE` statements:

```
'match_overall_test',
'CREATE TABLE `match_overall_test` (\n  
`id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  
`p1_id` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),\n  
KEY `ix_belgarath_match__player_id_1` (`p1_id`)\n) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1408022 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

'match_stat_test', 'CREATE TABLE `match_stat_test` (\n  
`id_` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n  
`match_overall_test_id` int DEFAULT NULL,\n  
`p1_serve_1` smallint DEFAULT NULL,\n  
PRIMARY KEY (`id_`),\n  
KEY `idx_match_stat__match_id` (`match_overall_test_id`) /*!80000 INVISIBLE */,\n  
CONSTRAINT `fk_match_stat_test__match_overall_test_id` FOREIGN KEY (`match_overall_test_id`) REFERENCES `match_overall_test` (`id_`)\n) 
ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=399686 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'
```

Comment: That's a very verbose way of saying mysql is not using an index which should be optimal. Try regenerating the index stats.

Comment: @symcbean - I've been told off if I don't include all the above details for a query optimisation question. I've never regenerated index stats before so that was a new one for me. I've now tried `OPTIMIZE TABLE` which for both tables returned: `Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead`. I also ran `ANALYZE TABLE` for good measure which came back with `OK`. I've run the query again and it's still scanning all the rows in `match_stat_test`...

Comment: Just `ANALYZE TABLE` is needed.  Even so, it rarely "fixes" anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the important index turned off (`INVISIBLE`).

Have these two "covering" indexes:

```
mot:  (p1_id, id_)
mst:  (match_overall_test_id, p1_serve_1)
```

You say you 'simplified' the query?  In that case, these indexes may not (or may) help the 'real' query.

Did you increase the value of `join_buffer_size`?  That may have helped.  but not nearly as much as having a suitable index.

Comment: Rick you are a bloody superstar. I didn't even know you could make indexes `INVISIBLE`. I must have clicked on it by accident in Workbench. I'll award the bounty as soon as it lets me :)